# Send Notification When Maintenance Plan Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there anyway to have Database Mail send a notification when a Maintenance Plan fails?  Or will this have to be done on the jobs that correspond to the Maintenance Plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use DB Mail then you would need to open the Maintenance Plan in BIDs and then add an Execute SQL Task that sends a mail by using a stored procedure.

Having said this however, what I would advise you do is to ad a send mail task to the maintenance plan, and then add an on failure precedence constraint between the tasks and the send mail task.

You could also achieve the same (more elegantly) by opening the maintenance plan in BIDS and adding an On Error event handler, and put the Send Mail task in there.